# Trying to wire a nest thermostat E in UK with 2 live wire and 2 neutrals

Tags: wiring, thermostat, boiler, combi

I live in the UK and am trying to replace a Honeywell WiFi thermostat with a Google Nest thermostat E. I have 2 3-core wires coming into my thermostat, 2 live and 2 neutral wires, 1 pair I believe are for the incoming power and the other possibly request for heat, I'm not sure but it's a combi boiler. One pair of wires originally connected to the left block of the Honeywell thermostat; the other obviously connected to the other side.